# Reading CSV File into R as a Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, tidyverse

I am trying to read into r as a data frame for the following link "https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/arable_land_pin.csv". I used both read.csv and read_csv from tidy verse but both do not work as one does not load and the other only has a single column (so it is not a formatting problem.) I am not sure how to proceed.

```
library(tidyverse)

arable_land <- read_csv("https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/arable_land_pin.csv")

arable_land %>% head
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Code
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/arable_land_pin.csv',
               stringsAsFactors = F,check.names = F)
```

Some output:

```
head(df)
       Entity Code Year Arable land needed to produce a fixed quantity of crops ((1.0 = 1961))
1 Afghanistan  AFG 1961                                                              1.0000000
2 Afghanistan  AFG 1962                                                              0.9842977
3 Afghanistan  AFG 1963                                                              1.0148702
4 Afghanistan  AFG 1964                                                              0.9391709
5 Afghanistan  AFG 1965                                                              0.9073304
6 Afghanistan  AFG 1966                                                              0.9268699
```

Or using `readr`:

```
#Code 2
df <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/arable_land_pin.csv')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 11,280 x 4
   Entity      Code   Year `Arable land needed to produce a fixed quantity of crops ((1.0 = 1961))`
   <chr>       <chr> <dbl>                                                                    <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan AFG    1961                                                                    1    
 2 Afghanistan AFG    1962                                                                    0.984
 3 Afghanistan AFG    1963                                                                    1.01 
 4 Afghanistan AFG    1964                                                                    0.939
 5 Afghanistan AFG    1965                                                                    0.907
 6 Afghanistan AFG    1966                                                                    0.927
 7 Afghanistan AFG    1967                                                                    0.832
 8 Afghanistan AFG    1968                                                                    0.812
 9 Afghanistan AFG    1969                                                                    0.792
10 Afghanistan AFG    1970                                                                    0.876
# ... with 11,270 more rows
```

Comment: thank you so read_csv is readr, not the save as tidy verse? and what did you do for the first solution? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/tree/master/data/2020/2020-09-01) where the csv file if from, they give you the code to import the data. Try:

```
arable_land <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/arable_land_pin.csv')
```

Comment: what is the difference between raw and not raw thanks!

Comment: If you enter the raw URL into your browser, you will see that it is just text in CSV format, unlike the non-raw which is a normal web page.